# Twilion & Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm creating functionality to send WhatsApp messages from the web using Twilio, And it is working in the local server but not on Heroku (the deployment server), I Have set all the environment variable but I'm not sure why it isn't working, Because Heroku is not logging any error about it
Thank you I'm waiting for your help

The Language I'm using is nodejs

Comment: Hi, Share some piece of code of your configurations.

Comment: THis is How I'. setting it up
```import twilio from 'twilio';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

export default new twilio(
  process.env.TWILIO_SID,
  process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
);
```

This is How I'm sending IT
```
import client from '../config/twilio-client';
const sendMessage = (message, to) => {
  client.messages
    .create({
      from: `whatsapp:+14155238886`,
      to: `whatsapp:${to}`,
      body: `${message}`,
    })
    .then((message) => message)
    .catch((err) => console.log('====', err, '===='));
};

export default sendMessage;

```

Comment: Try console.log(process.env.TWILIO_SID). If it shows undefined. Then there is some issue with dotenv file. Try removing dotenv module and set up the environment variables from settings in heroku.